# Including jquery in Symfony's encore does not work?

Tags: jquery, symfony, frameworks, webpack-encore

I installed symfony/webpack-encore and I want to use jquery in it. So i installed jquery (with yarn add jquery) and uncommented `const $ = require('jquery')` in the app.js file.

Everything compiles correctly but no js-code is executed until I delete the `const $ = require('jquery')`. (Everything runs fine without this line of code)

No errors, nothing.

I tried to reinstall encore, jquery and i even tried it with a new symfony-project.

app.js:

```
require('../css/app.scss'); 

const $ = require('jquery');

console.log('Hello Webpack Encore! Edit me in assets/js/app.js');
```

the log only works without the `const $ = require('jquery');`.

No output in console, no error messages, everything should work ok, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a global variable for jQuery.

```
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

Try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack.config.js try using:

```
 .autoProvidejQuery()
 .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
```

comment:

```
 //const $ = require('jquery');
```

And use jquery